# jquery toggle : loop effect + multiple toggles

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

With the toggle below ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSru2/)), I would like to be able to do the following:

1. To have a loop effect ie., being able to open & close the toggle as many times as I want. For now, I can only open and close the toggle once, because I can't get the second open link to command the fade effect again.
2. To have several toggles called on the same article (joomla website). I tried by duplicating the code and using `heading2`, `content2` but without success. Here's my code :

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <span class="heading">This is the beginning of the sentence. </span>
   <span class="content">This is the end of the sentence. </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $('<a href="#" id="read-more-link">[Read More]</a>').appendTo('.heading');
    $('#read-more-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $(this).next($(".content").fadeToggle(1000));
    });
    $('<a href="#" id="close-link">[close]</a>').appendTo('.content');
    $('#close-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $(this).next($(".content").fadeToggle(1000));
        $('<a href="#" id="read-more-link">[Read More]</a>').appendTo('.heading');

    });
});
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you use both `jQuery` and `$` interchangeably here?

Comment: 1. use delegation 2. use specific transversal method as .find(), .closest() etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answers !
@SetSailMedia : I am a newbie to the jquery world and I just copied the code from a website and tried to improve it. My bad, I have updated with $.

Comment: Thanks for your help @roasted, I am a newbie... Any examples please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example I think is simpler. It has less appending and removal of elements from the DOM:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Mq3B/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').after('<a href="#" class="toggle-link">[Read More]</a>');
    $(".content").hide();
    $('.toggle-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);

        if ($link.data('expanded') == true) {
            $link.data('expanded', false);
            $link.text('[Read More]');            
        } else {
            $link.data('expanded', true);
            $link.text('[Close]');
        }

        $link.prev(".content").fadeToggle(1000);
    });    

});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I am trying to understand how the if/else loop work!

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/data/. data() is a way to attach arbitrary data to an element. I assume that's what you're struggling with.

Comment: You're right this was the problem! You're a genius! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

1 - Since you want to use several read more / close links on the same page, you have to use classes instead of id, as you can't repeat ids.

2- To use classes, traversing must be relative to current element

The animations will have to be improved, but [here's a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/sSru2/1/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();

    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $('<a href="#" class="read-more">[Read More]</a>')
        .appendTo('.heading'); 

    $('.read-more').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $(this).closest('.heading').next(".content").fadeToggle(1000);  
    }); 

    $('<a href="#" class="close-link">[close]</a>').appendTo('.content');

    $('.close-link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.content').fadeToggle(1000)
            .prev('.heading').find('.read-more').fadeToggle(1000);

    });
});
```